# Total Spin Matrix Squared (Casimir Operator)

Tags: matrix, vector

I am trying to get Mathematica to compute the Casimir operator of a 4 particle system of spin $1/2$ fermions. I have the following code which does not do what I would like it to.

```
Stot = (1/2) {KroneckerProduct[sx, i, i, i] + 
KroneckerProduct[i, sx, i, i] + KroneckerProduct[i, i, sx, i] + 
KroneckerProduct[i, i, i, sx], 
KroneckerProduct[sy, i, i, i] + KroneckerProduct[i, sy, i, i] + 
KroneckerProduct[i, i, sy, i] + KroneckerProduct[i, i, i, sy], 
KroneckerProduct[sz, i, i, i] + KroneckerProduct[i, sz, i, i] + 
KroneckerProduct[i, i, sz, i] + KroneckerProduct[i, i, i, sz]}
DotProduct[Stot,Stot]
```

Stot is a vector, and each entry is a matrix. I would like to get the dot product of Stot with itself, but also want Mathematica to do the matrix multiplication inside the dot product. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute `Dot[#,#]` for each element `#` of the list and then sum up the results?!

```
{Sx,Sy,Sz}=With[{n=4},Table[Sum[KroneckerProduct@@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[2],n],j->1/2 PauliMatrix[i]],{j,1,n}],{i,1,3}]];
S2=Total[Dot[#,#]&/@%];
```

Which yields

> [image: S2]

Which is a matrix with three distinct eigenvalues: $0$ (with multiplicity $2$), $1$ (with multiplicity $6$) and $2$ (with multiplicity $5$) corresponding to two spin-$0$, six spin-$1$ and five spin-$2$ states.